# NPCs Keep Wandering in to my Fist Fights

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Maybe I just don't remember it quite right, but I've been finding a lot of NPCs in the world that want to challenge me to fist fights. They all also happen to have 100 gold on them for said fights but whatever.

Regardless, I've been noticing that a lot of NPCs tend to gather around and watch us fight. They mostly say the same things like "show that snowback how to fight!" and the like, and the crowd can range anywhere from 1 to 5 or 6 NPCs. They tend to wander into the middle of my fights though; I tend to move around a lot to dodge the punches while still landing my own, but the NPCs just wander in and out, yelling various things. I even hit one during a fight, and the fight ended and everyone pulled out swords and attacked me.

Is there any way to keep the NPCs from wandering aimlessly into my fights?

Comment: Brawls are so buggy that I just save, brawl, wait until somebody pulls a sword, reload the save, and start over... :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find an object to circle around, like a vertical pillar in the Whiterun bar.

Constantly back up in circles around the thing, and punch your enemy as they move toward you.

This should result in you being hit almost never (once you get the timing and distance down). It will also constrain the fight to a very small area, entirely within the circle of onlookers, while also putting an object in the middle of your fight so that no one can possible walk into the middle of it.